# Plot bars with no observations

Tags: python, pandas, plot

This code produces the following plot:

```
df.groupby(['bin'],observed=True)['Clicked'].value_counts(ascending=True,normalize=True).unstack().plot(kind='bar' ,stacked=True,color=['C0','C3'],alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(title="Clicked on:")
plt.title("")
```

[image]

This is the data snippet after the unstack():

```
Clicked       Real & Rep    Rep only
bin     
(-0.5, -0.45]   0.333333    0.666667
(-0.4, -0.35]   NaN         1.000000
(-0.25, -0.2]   0.500000    0.500000
(-0.15, -0.1]   0.400000    0.600000
(-0.1, -0.05]   0.400000    0.600000
(-0.05, 0.0]    0.488889    0.511111
(0.0, 0.05] 0.228782    0.771218
(0.05, 0.1] 0.141818    0.858182
(0.1, 0.15] 0.067797    0.932203
(0.15, 0.2] 0.121622    0.878378
(0.2, 0.25] 0.054054    0.945946
(0.25, 0.3] 0.089744    0.910256
```

As you can see some bins don't have observations [(-0.45,-0.4),(-0.35,-0.3),(-0.3,-0.25),(-0.2,-0.15)].
How could I do so the missing bins are shown in the plot (empty)?
I had to include that `observed=True` in the `groupby`, otherwise I was getting and error.

Comment: Please run *df.groupby(['bin'],observed=True)['Clicked'].value_counts(ascending=True,normalize=True).unstack()* on your source data and post the result.
I suppose that some intermediate step is needed before *plot*, but I have no time to generate this data on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have only some intervals is that you passed
*observed=True*, so the result of *groupby* contains not all intervals
(intervals for which there are no source data are omitted).

I generated the source DataFrame with the index containing all cosecutive intervals
in your range:

```
Clicked        Real & Rep  Rep only
bin                                
(-0.5, -0.45]    0.333333  0.666667
(-0.45, -0.4]         NaN       NaN
(-0.4, -0.35]         NaN  1.000000
(-0.35, -0.3]         NaN       NaN
(-0.3, -0.25]         NaN       NaN
(-0.25, -0.2]    0.500000  0.500000
(-0.2, -0.15]         NaN       NaN
(-0.15, -0.1]    0.400000  0.600000
(-0.1, -0.05]    0.400000  0.600000
(-0.05, 0.0]     0.488889  0.511111
(0.0, 0.05]      0.228782  0.771218
(0.05, 0.1]      0.141818  0.858182
(0.1, 0.15]      0.067797  0.932203
(0.15, 0.2]      0.121622  0.878378
(0.2, 0.25]      0.054054  0.945946
(0.25, 0.3]      0.089744  0.910256
```

Then I ran your code and got:

[image]

As you see, with **all** intervals.

The first suggestion is to drop *observed* parameter.

Or, if you want to have only some part of your range, *reindex* your
intermediate result with the index containing proper range of intervals.

Another suggestion is to move the legend outside the image.
To do it, run:

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=['C0','C3'], alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(title='Clicked on:', loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1.0))
plt.title("");
```

and the legend will be to the right of the image.

Comment: it's not letting me run the `groupby.value_counts()` without the `observed=True`. The error is `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (18,) (12,)`

Comment: Try *reindex* to have the source with all intervals.

Comment: I tried `df.groupby(['bin']).apply(lambda x: x.Clicked.value_counts(ascending=True,normalize=True)).unstack().reindex(df['bin'].unique())` but the output is still missing those empty bins. Should I put the reindex somewhere else?

Comment: You should create the index, including all intervals, in a separate instruction. Then you should pass it to *reindex*. What you did doesn't change anything.

Comment: that df['bin'].unique() piece creates a list with all categories (including those without observations), how else should I do it? In the source dataframe that you put in your answer, how did you add the missing categories? Was it manually?

Comment: Yes, I created it manually.